# Samsung Gear Fit Api Android

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-gear-fit

I have buyed a Samsung sm-r350 gear fit device. Now i want make an Android application that reads the heart rate parameters through and shows that parameter into my activity. I see the Health SDK of samsung but i must be a partener. Theres another method to retrieve that parameters?
Thanks

Comment: U need not be a partner. U can request for the SDK from Samsung and use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an SDK that works with the Gear Fit. I am trying to figure it out currently.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/gear-fit/development/samsung-gear-fit-sdk-available-t2872803

Comment: Hi, 

is there a way to enable debugging in Samsung Gear Fit SM-R350? 
I have tried but with no success ...